# Gradle flavors vs. Git branching

Tags: android, git, gradle, project-management

I am at a point where it'd be great to maintain a demo version, a dev version, and a stable version for my Android app. I'm still kind of new to Gradle and was wondering what are the advantages / disadvantages of using product flavors in Gradle vs just maintaining a separate branch altogether in Git?

After reading up on how to use product flavors, it feels like maintaining and building code from different branches is a neater solution, instead of having multiple flavors folders in my src directory. Am I wrong in thinking so? I just want to know if I'm doing this correctly.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: IMHO, demo, dev, and stable are not product flavors.

Comment: Thanks. The tutorials I went through created demo as a product flavor, even the one from developer.android.com (https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants), so that influenced my thinking. I guess I'll continue using git branches itself then.

Comment: To be clear, I think that their demo/full split is referring to the exposed feature set of the app. Here, "demo" literally meaning "some demonstration version of the app", where "full" is the real app. That's not unreasonable for product flavors. Product flavors are when you want to ship different versions of the same app, from mostly the same code, for different distribution scenarios. My main example is having `google`, `amazon`, and `blackberry` flavors for different in-app purchasing APIs. While the app is mostly the same, you need to use the right IAP API for the distribution channel.

Comment: To me, "dev" and "stable" are not the same code, from a chronological standpoint. Either you're using branches and parallel timelines, or "dev" is code that is newer than "stable". In either case, product flavors don't really model that well.

Comment: Aha, I think I got it. The API example you mentioned made it clearer. And yes, I am using the branches in parallel for dev and stable. Thank you for clearing it up :)