# Flavors / Branches to store different IP connection

Tags: android, git, version-control, android-gradle-plugin

For an app that connects to a server, I'd like to have a version that connects to my local server and another version that connects to a publicly accessible server.

I could do than with a separate git branch, or I could set up flavors and have different versions of the same xml file with the connection strings. Searching SO led me to [Gradle flavors vs. Git branching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28169625/2729605) but unfortunately it doesn't have an answer.

Is there a 'mandatory' way to do that? If not, what is the preferred way?

Comment: Gradle flavors is the best, easy and preferred way. See this for help https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use different BuildTypes for that:

```
buildTypes {
    local {
        buildConfigField "String", "HOST", "\"localip\""
    }
    public {
        buildConfigField "String", "HOST", "\"publicip\""
    }
}
```

And wherever you need to use it, do the following

```
String ipToUse = BuildConfig.HOST;
```

Comment: +1 Also, you can create a completely different set of Java classes for different build types in this method if needed. Very nice flexibility.